# Hystrix Command in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring cloud starter gateway 2.0.1.RELEASE along with Starter netflix hystrix. Is it possible to provide a HystrixCommand in route definition like below?.

```
builder.routes()
        .route( r -> r.path("path")
                    .and().method(HttpMethod.GET)
                    .filters(f -> f.hystrix("myHystrixCommandName"))
        .uri("/destination")
                    .id("route_1"));
```

My goal is to execute a fallback method without forwarding the request to a fallback uri.
Also I cannot use static fallback uri option as I need path params and request params to determine the fallback response. Any help is highly appreciated!.

Comment: Not currently as it is built. Why can't you fallback to a uri? In this example https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-gateway-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demogateway/DemogatewayApplication.java#L21 the fallback uri is only "forward:/hystrixfallback". This allows you to use a local webflux endpoint where you can access the request parameters, headers etc... With a custom command you couldn't access those things.

Comment: Thank you @spencergibb for your response. I couldn't figure out how to access the actual URI as I have an id that is a path param. My route looks like /api/{appid}/users/{userid} and I need to be able to access appId and userId in the forward URI. All the examples that I'm encountering are static URIs.

Comment: Put a `ServerHttpRequest` as a parameter. It's a normal spring webflux app.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. This is how I solved it:

**First**, These are the routes:

```
builder.routes()
    .route( r -> r.path("/api/{appid}/users/{userid}")
                .and().method(HttpMethod.GET)
                .filters(f -> f.hystrix("myHystrixCommandName")
                               .setFallbackUri("forward:/hystrixfallback"))
    .uri("/destination")
                .id("route_1"));
```

The ***path*** predicate processes the url and extracts the path variables, those are saved into `ServerWebExchange.getAttributes()`, with a key defined as `PathRoutePredicate.URL_PREDICATE_VARS_ATTR` or `ServerWebExchangeUtils.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE`

You can find more information about path predicate [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi_gateway-request-predicates-factories.html#_path_route_predicate_factory)

**Second**, I created a `@RestController` to handle the forward from Hystrix injecting the `ServerWebExchange`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hystrixfallback")
public class ServiceFallBack {
    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String get(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
        //Get the PathMatchInfo
        PathPattern.PathMatchInfo pathMatchInfo = serverWebExchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);

        //Get the template variables
        Map<String, String> urlTemplateVariables = pathMatchInfo.getUriVariables();

        //TODO Logic using path variables

        return "result";
    }
}
```